# How does this equation follow from Green's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u \in C^2(\overline \Omega \times [0, \infty))$ and $c(x) \geq c_0 > 0$ in $\Omega$. I have the following equation in my notes:
$$
\int_\Omega c^2(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_t \; \mathrm dx 
= - \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left( c^2(x) \nabla u \right) u_t \; \mathrm dx
+ \int_{\partial \Omega} c^2(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} u_t \; \mathrm ds
$$
I assume, this equation was derived from Green's formula:
$$
\int_\Omega v \Delta u \; \mathrm dx = - \int_\Omega \nabla v \cdot \nabla u \; \mathrm dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \; \mathrm ds \; ,
$$
but I don't see how. In the case where $c(x) \equiv 1$, it's exactly Green's formula, but I don't see how it works for a more general $c(x)$. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule,
$$\nabla \cdot \left( c^2(x) \, \nabla u \, u_t \right) 
= \nabla \cdot \left(c^2(x) \, \nabla u \right) u_t + c^2(x) \, \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_t$$

Integrating this over $\Omega$ gives
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left( c^2(x) \, \nabla u \, u_t \right) \, \mathrm dx
= \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left(c^2(x) \, \nabla u \right) u_t  \, \mathrm dx
+ \int_\Omega c^2(x) \, \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_t \, \mathrm dx$$

By [Gauss' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_theorem) (a.k.a. [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)), the first integral can be rewritten as
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} c^2(x) \, \nabla u \, u_t \, \cdot n \, \mathrm ds
= \int_{\partial \Omega} c^2(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \, u_t \, \mathrm ds$$

Rearranging the terms we end up with
$$\int_\Omega c^2(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_t \, \mathrm dx 
= - \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left( c^2(x) \nabla u \right) u_t \, \mathrm dx
+ \int_{\partial \Omega} c^2(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} u_t \, \mathrm ds$$

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general form of Green's First Identity (which frankly should be given as the standard one, considering how simple it is): let $u \in C^2$, $v \in C^1$, $a \in C^1$. Then the product rule gives
$$ \nabla \cdot (av\nabla u) = \nabla \cdot (a\nabla u)v + a \nabla u \cdot \nabla v, $$
and integrating this gives
$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (av\nabla u) \, dx = \int_{\Omega} \left( \nabla \cdot (a\nabla u)v + a \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \right) dx $$
Using the Divergence Theorem on the left and rearranging gives
$$ \int_{\Omega} a \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx = -\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (a\nabla u)v \, dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} av \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \, ds, $$
into which you can substitute to get what you want.

Comment: Why are $v$ and $a$ restricted to $C^1$ or was that a typo?

Comment: The first integral on the right differentiates $av$, so it's simplest to ask for $C^1$ for that derivative to exist.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I actually realised that almost immediately after asking and thought I'd actually deleted my comment. Guess not!

Comment: Thank you. I did not see how to substitute into this version of the Green's theorem since I do not have a $\Delta$-operator in my equation. But it's useful to know this more general version of the Green's theorem.

Comment: @aexl Oops, I had the wrong grouping in the product rule. Fixed.